# Values don't show up in ListView

Tags: c#, listview, .net-core

I have a problem with `ListView`. I am trying to call `AddToListView` function which is in `UCForm` from `MainForm` but nothing shows up on the `ListView`. Strangely, when I call `AddToListView` on `UCForm` initialization everything works correctly.
**AddToListView function:**

```
public void AddToListView()
{
    var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" });
    listView.Items.Add(item1);
}
```

**Button click in MainForm:**

```
UCForm uf = new UCForm();
private void btnAddToList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     uf.AddToListView();
}
```

**More info:** There are 4 columns already set up. `FullRowSelect` is set to true. `GridLines` are set to true.
**What I've tried:** [Add item to ListView from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957382/add-item-to-listview-from-another-class)
and [How to access a ListView control on another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168071/how-to-access-a-listview-control-on-another-form).

Both of the posts didn't help me. My goal is to add values to `ListView` from another class.

Comment: If you have `UCForm` in the designer, then this `UCForm uf = new UCForm();` creates a different one. If so, you need to access the one in the designer. Like `UCForm1.AddToListView();`.

Comment: What is UCForm? Can you post it too?

Comment: @Sergey it's a Form with a ListView and it also contains AddToListView function inside.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you. You solved my issue. I completly forgot about it.